# How to fix ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently developing an angular application with a django backend, I use `ngModel` to retrieve lists in selects which allow me to filter a list of checkboxes, however I want to insert in my `Reactiveforms` the identifier of the selected gears, and i have conflicts between some ngmodels and my `Reactiveform` doesn't quite understand why And when i add the `formArrayName` i don't have my select list anymore either, i wonder if it's also a conflict with ngmodel do you have any thoughts on this?
I however used the method `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: ​​true}"`

[console error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQAw.png

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
<label for="name">Nom de la flotte à créer</label>

<input class="Nflotte" formControlName="name" type="text"  #flotteName placeholder="Nom de la flotte" required>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">   
        <wcs-select [(ngModel)]="SelectedSerie" name="SelectedSerie" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Série" id="leselectg" (ngModelChange)="getEnginBySeries()">
            
            <wcs-select-option *ngFor="let serie of series" [value]="serie">{{
                serie.code_serie_materiel }}</wcs-select-option>
        </wcs-select>   
        <wcs-select [(ngModel)]="SelectedSousSerie" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Sous-série" id="leselectg" (ngModelChange)="getEnginBySousSeries()">
            <wcs-select-option *ngFor="let sousSerie of SelectedSerie?.sousseries" [value]="sousSerie">{{
                sousSerie.code_serie_materiel }}</wcs-select-option>
        </wcs-select>
        <wcs-select [(ngModel)]="SelectedVariante" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Variantes" id="leselectg" (ngModelChange)="getEnginByVariante()">
            <wcs-select-option *ngFor="let variante of SelectedSousSerie?.variantes">
                {{ variante.code_serie_materiel }}
            </wcs-select-option>
        </wcs-select>       
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fsearch one">
        
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="search">

                <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="search-text" aria-describedby="search-text" 
                [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Rechercher un engin" [value]="">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>  
            
    </div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class=" three">

        
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">

<form  novalidate>

<table class="blueTable" formArrayName="engins">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Sélectionner tout les engins</th>
    <th >num_facade</th>
    <th >num_immatriculation_ef</th>
    
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="margin: 15px;" >
        <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="masterSelected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="list_name" value="m1"
        (change)="checkUncheckAll()"/> 

        <tr  class="list-group" [formControlName]="i" style="list-style-type: none;" *ngFor="let engin of form.controls?.engins?.controls | appFilter: searchText; let i = index" >
            <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="engin.isSelected"   name="list_engins[]" formControlName="checked" value="{{engin[i].identifiant}}"
        (change)="isAllSelected()"/>
            <td>{{engin.num_facade}}</td>
            <td>{{engin.num_immatriculation_ef}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>    
</form>
</div>
</form>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FlotteService } from 'src/app/services/flotte.service';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
import { Engins, SerieBase, SousSerieEngin, VariantesEngin } from 'src/app/interface/serie';
import { SerieEngin } from 'src/app/interface/serie';
import { Flotte } from 'src/app/interface/flotte';
import { VisualisationComponent } from '../visualisation/visualisation.component';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Emitters } from 'src/app/emitters/emitters';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

export class FlotteComponent implements OnInit {
  message: any;
  error: any;
  SelectedSerie?: SerieEngin;
  SelectedSousSerie?: SousSerieEngin;
  SelectedVariante?: VariantesEngin;
  SelectedFlotte?: Flotte;
  SelectionSerie: String = '';


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {withCredentials: true}).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.message = `Bonjour ${res.username}`;
        Emitters.authEmitter.emit(true);
      },
    );
    this.getAllFlottes()
    this.flotteservice.getSeries2()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.series = response;

      }  
      )

      this.engins.forEach(engin => {
        if (engin.value) {
          engin.value.forEach((checkbox: any) => {
            
          
          })
        }
      })
 this.engins = [];
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      // control for radio exemple
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      // control for Checkbox exemple
      engins: new FormArray([]),
      calculateur: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      type_fichier: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    });
    // bind existing value to form control
    this._patchValues();
  }

private _patchValues(): void {
    // get array control
    const formArray = this.form.get('engins') as FormArray;
    // loop for each existing value
    this.engins.forEach((engin) => {
      // add new control to FormArray
      formArray.push(
        // here the new FormControl with item value from RADIO_LIST_FROM_DATABASE
        new FormGroup({
          fengins: new FormControl(engin.identifiant),
          checked: new FormControl(engin.checked),
        })
      );
    });
  }  

 submitForm(): void {


    const { value } = this.form;
    // get selected fruit from FormGroup value
    const selectedEngin =
      value?.engins?.filter((f: Engins) => f.checked) || [];

    // form value binded
    console.log('current form value: ', value);  
    console.log('only selected form value: ', selectedEngin);
    // original value from database not change
    console.log('original engins list: ', this.engins);
    this.result = {
      name: value?.name || '',
      selectedEngin,
      calculateur: value?.calculateur || '',
      type_fichier: value?.type_fichier|| '',
   
     }
     this.api.registerFlotte(this.form.value)
     .subscribe((res:any)=>{console.log(res)});

  }






}
```

Comment: are you sure that `wcs-select` not admit formControlName? Be careful, some select controls, allow store an array when "multiple" property is used. then remember that you need use a FormControl, **not** a FormArray. yes a FormControl can sotre an array or another complex object

Comment: oh thanks I thought I had to use a formarray absolutely, I'll try using only formcontrol

Comment: Well I always have the same error with formcontrol, I have the impression that my code does not take into account the [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: if you use [(ngModel)] **not** use formControlName (in the same tag). I want say that if you're using Reactive Forms, you should use `formControlName`. use [(ngModel)] inside a <form [formGroup]="form"> is for "inputs" that **not belong** to the FormGroup. My first comment about "select multiple" was that I don't know about the "wsc-select", but, e.g. mat-select multiple mannage a FormControl not a FormArray. e.g. you use `form.get('multiselect').setValue([1,2])` and I imagine that wsc-select works similar -but I'm not pretty sure-

Comment: ok i'm trying to make it work with formcontrol but i can't get my checkbox list, in my form i get to get a text input and radio button options but not the checkbox list, and i I need the ngmodel for my "select all checkboxes" function I don't know how else to do it, I'll try to find a way not to put them in the same tag